# Populate escape sequence character in Combo Box shows empty spaces

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, truetype

I am binding a combo box with all the characters from ttf file. Combo box displays empty space for some of the characters like \n  \r \t \a etc. I am not able to find the reason why it does so.

Here is my code to populate all symbols

```
var families = Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri(fontFilePath));
            foreach (FontFamily family in families)
            {
                var typefaces = family.GetTypefaces();
            foreach (Typeface typeface in typefaces)
            {
                GlyphTypeface glyph;
                typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph);
                IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;

                foreach (var item in characterMap.Values)
                {
                    char temp = Convert.ToChar(item);
                    string str = string.Format("{0}", temp);
                    if (!listOfString.Contains(str))
                    {
                        listOfString.Add(str);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        listOfString.Sort();
        ddlSymbols.ItemsSource = listOfString;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think \t should display?

Comment: The combobox should display \t, \n instead of empty spaces.

Comment: But \t is a tab.  You really think a combobox should not display a tab as a tab?  If you want the literal then you are going to need to escape the control character and format characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, some of the characters are called "Escape sequences" and are special characters.

- \' (UTF-16: \u0027) = allow to enter a `'` in a character literal, e.g. '\''
- \" (UTF-16: \u0022) = allow to enter a `"` in a string literal, e.g. "this is the
  double quote (\") character"
- \   \u005c  allow to enter a `\` character in a character or string literal, e.g. '\' or "this is the backslash
  (\) character"
- \0 (UTF-16: \u0000) = allow to enter the character with code 0
- \a (UTF-16: \u0007) = alarm (usually the HW beep)
- \b (UTF-16: \u0008) = back-space
- \f (UTF-16: \u000c) = form-feed (next page)
- \n (UTF-16: \u000a) = line-feed (next line)
- \r (UTF-16: \u000d) = carriage-return (move to the beginning of the line)
- \t (UTF-16: \u0009) = (horizontal-) tab
- \v (UTF-16: \u000b) = vertical-tab

So when you map your characters, their special behaviour is used.